# Excel How to filter column when cells includes several strings separated by comma?

Tags: excel, filter

In my excel file, I am have column:

```
Board
dk-s1,dk-s5
dk-s2,dk-s8, sk-9
sk-d7
```

The filter selections checkboxes shows:

```
(dk-s1,dk-s5)
(dk-s2,dk-s8, sk-9)
(sk-d7)
```

I am wondering that is there a way to show a single string in each checkboxes?
for example `(dk-s1)(dk-s5)`....
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this without seperating the values first.  To do that you could:

1. Move the column to last column (to right).
2. select all data you need to split.
3. go to: Data--> Text to columns--> Delimited--> check "Comma"--> Finish.
4. Add column titles for the new columns
5. go to: Data--> Filter and toggle filter off/on

Now you have new columns for selecting all your different options.

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to mark it solved :)